# Counting the number of digit occurrences in a string

Tags: java

I have a lab that involves counting the number of digits and the number letters in a string. I actually got the method of counting letters from my java book so I'm still not too sure on how exactly it works, but when I tried to recreate that method but for the digits part of the lab, the output was wrong. If somebody could point me in the right direction I'd greatly appreciate it.

**The correct output is supposed to be:**

1800flowers

e appears 1 time

f appears 1 time

l appears 1 time

o appears 1 time

r appears 1 time

s appears 1 time

w appears 1 time

0 appears 2 times

1 appears 1 time

8 appears 1 time

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)

**The output I'm getting is:**
Enter a string:

1800flowers

e appears 1 time

f appears 1 time

l appears 1 time

o appears 1 time

r appears 1 time

s appears 1 time

w appears 1 time

0 appears 1 times

1 appears 1 times

2 appears 1 times

3 appears 1 times

4 appears 0 times

5 appears 0 times

6 appears 0 times

7 appears 0 times

8 appears 0 times

9 appears 0 times

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)
        public class Lab12 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = new String("");
    System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
    s = input.nextLine();
    int[] counts = countletters(s.toLowerCase());
    for (int i =0; i < counts.length; i++){
        if (counts[i] != 0){
            System.out.println((char)('a' + i) + " appears " + counts[i] + ((counts[i] == 1? " time": " times")));
        }
    }
    System.out.println("");
    int[] counts2 = countDigits(s);
    for (int i = 0; i <counts2.length; i++){

        System.out.println(i + " appears " + counts2[i] + " times " );

    }


}
public static int[] countDigits(String s){
    int[] counts = new int[10];
    for (int i = 0; i <s.length(); i++){
        if (Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))){
            counts[(int)s.charAt(i - '0')]++;
        }
    }
    return counts;
}
public static int[] countletters(String s){

    int[] counts = new int[26];

       for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){

           if (Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i))){
               counts[(s.charAt(i) - 'a')]++;
           }

    }
    return counts;
```

Comment: Can you show us a sample input and output you are getting?

Comment: Define `wrong` please

Comment: the number of digits or the number of unique digits?

Comment: I edited my post to display my sample input and what the correct output should be. Also I included what the "wrong" output looks like. @Prateek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
counts[i]++;
```

It should be:

```
counts[(int)s.charAt(i) - '0']++;
```

Comment: I got a StringIndexOutofBounds Exception when I changed it to that. :/

Answer (score 1):

You can "Count the number of digit occurrences in a string" this way

```
string[] digits = Regex.Split(input, @"\D+");
int i = digits.length;
```

Edit: The question was firstly tagged with C# !!

This is the java equivalent:

```
String Input = "Count the 15 number of 454 digits 12";
String[] s = Input.split("\\D+");
System.out.println(s.length-1);
```

Comment: I'm sorry! I made sure I tagged java, I don't know what happened.

Comment: @DeathWish: Check the last edit, apparently java doesn't do this the same way C# does, anyway I figured that if you subtract one from the string length, the output is correct

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this line:

```
counts[i]++;
```

It should be:

```
int offset = (int)'0';
counts[(int)s.charAt(i) - offset]++;
```

because you should be incrementing the counter for the digit you found, not for the position in the string.

Comment: I changed it to that and I get an Array out of bounds exception.

Comment: *Why* should it be that way?

Comment: I changed the code to not throw index out of bounds. @user987339 is right to subtract '0' in his answer, because `(int)s.charAt(i)` gives you the value of the character in the code page, not the value of the digit it represents. So to reset it back to 0, you should subtract the offset.

Comment: I got a StringIndexOutofBounds Exception when I changed it to  @user987339 's answe.

Comment: Also, using the variable offset, i get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: It's because you pasted it incorrectly. You have: `counts[(int)s.charAt(i - '0')]` but it should be: `counts[(int)s.charAt(i) - '0']`. Look at the parenthesis closely.

Comment: @Daniel Gabriel it was really bad copy paste.

Comment: @user987339 it seems that way.